# What does the Cross-Validation procedure try to estimate?

Tags: cross-validation

Let's consider an untrained classifier $f$ (with fixed hyperparameters) and a dataset $S = (x_i, y_i)_{i=1...n}$ sampled i.i.d from some unknown distribution $P$.

What is the unknown quantity that a k-fold CV tries to estimate? Is it:

1. the expected accuracy of the classifier $f_S$ trained on $S$: $E_{(x_i,y_i)\sim P}[1-L(y_i, f_S(x_i))]$, where $L$ is the 0-1 loss. In other words we don't care about the variability coming from the training set.
2. the quantity above, but averaged over all training sets of size $n$: $E_S E_{(x_i,y_i)\sim P}[1-L(y_i, f_S(x_i))]$.

The answer is not clear from the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)). My guess is that CV tries to estimate the second definition, as it seems more relevant for the purpose of model selection or algorithm comparison.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.00673